# Redirect 301 directive for Apache has no effect for URL with query string

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I have this old link `http://www.example.com/?page_id=617/` that I want to redirect to the home page.  I've tried to implement this redirect with:

```
Redirect 301 /?page_id=617/ https://www.example.com/
```

After apply this change, nothing happened. The old URL doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 5):

You can't match the query string with a mod_alias `Redirect`. You need to use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive instead. And match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in a `RewriteCond` directive.

Try the following instead, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=617/$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/? [R=302,L]
```

Note that this matches the *exact* query string `?page_id=617/`. Change the *pattern* to `^page_id=617` to match a query string that simply *starts* `?page_id=617`.

Change the 302 to 301 only when you are sure it's working OK. (To avoid erroneous redirects being cached by the browser.)

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is required to removed the query string from the request (otherwise this gets passed through to the target URL). On Apache 2.4+ you can use the `QSD` flag instead.